# How can I view the output of Shopify custom pixel?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm writing a Shopify custom pixel and as part of it, I need to console.log data to the browser to see what is being returned.

I have something simple like this

```
analytics.subscribe('checkout_started', event => {
  // Example for accessing event data
  const checkout = event.data.checkout;
  console.log('checkout', checkout)
});
```

But when I load a checkout, nothing logs to the console? Not sure how you're supposed to write these things if you can't test in the browser?